# How to create knowledge base for sharepoint online modern sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create knowledge base for sharepoint online modern sites but i am not understanding how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent article for your reference:

[How to build an awesome Knowledge Base Wiki in SharePoint Online using modern pages](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-build-an-awesome-knowledge-base-wiki-in-sharepoint-online-using-modern-pages/)